# magento 2 shows 404 error on product detail page

Tags: magento, magento2

I am getting 404 error on **ALL** product detail pages. This happened right after I imported new products. Yes I did reindex several times. Everything else loads as it should. I thought maybe it is because of url rewrite module but if that was the case then I had to have the same problem for categories but I don't. Also I created a new product to see maybe there is a problem with my import file but the new product throw 404 as well.
Here is an url example for product detail(throws 404 error): `http://example.com/index.php/09wx6359.html`
Here is an url example for categories which works fine: `http://example.com/index.php/product/resistor/film/metal.html`. So Problem is not re-indexing or rewrite url. I'm using Magento 2.0.4. Please HELP

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was from my template files. There is an error in one of the files that renders product detail page. When I changed my template to Luma it got fixed. Such a relief I'm so happy now

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened when i migrated a new staging environment. I copied the production db and uploaded my develop branch code. after all Megento commands the product pages kept saying 404.

After truncating the tables:

- report_event
- session
- customer_visitor

Deleting some folders in the var folder with command:

```
    rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/pagecache var/di
```

My product pages are working again. Magento ver. 2.1.8

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help newbies to Magento 2.

If you are getting 404 message while accessing product page or category page, few things might not right. Thus, the simple one might be because of your catalog configuration that is:

**Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Search Engine Optimization->Product URL Suffix**

**Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Search Engine Optimization->Category URL Suffix**

If this value is `.html`and you are accessing product or category URL like this https://www.qyqhair.co.uk/brazilian  **you will get 404 error**. The best way to get correct URL, in this case, will be to add the `.html` suffix i.e. `/brazilian.html`.
If you want to  access the page as shown in the sample URL, then, you need to remove the `.html` value from **Product URL Suffix** and or both **Category URL Suffix** and leave it blank.

You might want to also run this command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento cache:clean` after you made the changes.

Hope this help someone, one day.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue and fixed in following ways:

- correct 'special price from' date
- assign 'default category'
- run command index:reindex
- flush cache

Issue resolved.